# Writing an object to an existing json file and wrapping the contents with '[ ]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, markdown

Ok, so I'm learning javascript (coming from c++) by writing a utility that takes in .md (markdown) files and parses/transforms the file to an html then to a json object, then writes that object to an existing json file in a format that follows my specification.

to be clear see the following pipeline:

**loop through a directory of .md files** -> **push each file through a parse/transform phase that turns markdown to html** -> **push the html and parsed data to a json file**

*please note that I have most of the logic completed, however, I need help with a formatting issue...please read the full post before closing or answering. Thank you!*

main logic of the pipeline:

```
export function transformMdtoHtmltoJson(dest, post) {
    
    const file = matter.read(post);
    
    const title = file.data.title;
    const date = file.data.date;
    const description = file.data.description;
    const socials = file.data.socials;
    
    unified()
        .use(remarkParse)
        .use(remarkRehype)
        .use(rehypeStringify)
        .process(file.content)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                toJson(dest, title, date, description, result.value, socials);
            },
            (err) => {
                throw err;
            }
          );
}
```

My plugin to write the json to an existing file:

```
class Data {

  constructor(title, date, description, content, socials) {
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.content = content;
    this.socials = socials;
  }
}


function createNewMember(title, date, description, content, socials) {
        let newMemer = new Data(title, date, description, content, socials);
        let result = {};
        return result = {
                "title": newMemer.title,
                "date": newMemer.date,
                "description": newMemer.description,
                "content": newMemer.content,
                "socials": newMemer.socials
        }
}

export async function toJson(inFile, title, data, description, content, socials) {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(inFile),
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });
  const lines = [];
  for await (const line of rl) {
    lines.push(line);
  }
  let object = createNewMember(title, data, description, content, socials);
  lines.push(JSON.stringify(object));
  let string = lines.join('') + ',';
  writeFile(inFile, string);
}

function writeFile(inFile, data) {
          fs.writeFile(inFile, data, { flag: "a+" }, (err) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log("The file has been saved!");
                          }
                          );
}
```

my inputs:
a directory of posts
`~/path/to/posts/post1.md`
`~/path/to/posts/post2.md`
`~/path/to/posts/post3.md`

contents of post (the same for each to make things easy)

```
---
title: Hello this is a test
date: 05/04/2022
description: this is a test
socials:
---

# Hello
## subhello
```

my target: `~/path/to/post.json`

my entry point function:

```
const postDir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts');
const destDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '_data');
const jsonFile = 'post.json';

const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postDir);

async function generatePosts(fileNames, postDir, destDir, jsonFile) {
          fileNames.forEach( (fileName) => {
                        const fullPath = path.join(postDir, fileName);
                        const destPath = path.join(destDir, jsonFile)
                        transformMdtoHtmltoJson(destPath, fullPath);
                });
}


generatePosts(fileNames, postDir, destDir, jsonFile);
```

my output: `~/path/to/post.json`

```
{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null},
{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null},
{"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null
},
```

What I want to do is wrap this output in [ ] brackets so that I can loop through them as an array.

Desired output:

```
[
{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null},
{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null},
{"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null
},
]
```

I have tried several ways, but they all just wrap each individual post with [ ] resulting in

```
[{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null}],
[{
"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null}],
[{"title":"Hello this is a test",
"date":"05/04/2022",
"description":"this is a test",
"content":"<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h2>subhello</h2>",
"socials":null
}],
```

Which is not what I want. I had thought that maybe doing this with callbacks would be the solution but I have not been able to get it right. Please help.

Here is a link to the github repo https://github.com/giannicrivello/MarkdownToHtmlToJson

Comment: `writeFile(inFile, JSON.stringify([output]));` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that is something I tried and it outputs the undesired effect of wrapping each post contents in [ ]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have went about it the wrong way. From what I understand from your code (with libraries i'm not familiar with), what you're doing is writing your file for each .md file you have, might not be the most efficient.

What I would do so you don't have to refactor what you've done:

```
export async function toJson(inFile, title, data, description, content, socials) {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(inFile);
  
  // Maybe "buffer.toString() ?? '[]';", not sure if that works
  // This is done to instanciate an empty array if the file is empty
  const fileContent = buffer.toString() ? buffer.toString() : '[]';

  // Parses the json into an array of objects.
  // (Obviously only works if the json file is empty or an array at root)
  var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(fileContent);
  
  // Puts your object at begging of the array
  // might as well use .push() if you want it at then end
  arrayOfObjects.unshift({
    title,
    data,
    description,
    content,
    socials,
  });
  
  // I REALLY recommend you use those extra arguments (null, 2)
  // or similar ones so your file don't look too wierd reading it
  writeFile(inFile, JSON.stringify(fullObjectArray, null, 2));
}
```

This may not work since I couldn't really try what you've done, didn't know how to download the packages, but it should lead you in the right way to fix what's going wrong for you :)

**EDIT:** While ready back what you did I noticed that both the function `createNewMember` and class `Data` could be removed and replaced with a basic "Object declaration" in your `toJson` function. You could possible keep your Data class if you intended to re-use it elsewhere...

**Edit 2:** I removed everything unnecessary from your code and made it so it writes your `post.json` file only once. The whole thing could be this:

```
export function transformMdtoHtmltoJson(dest, post) {
  const file = matter.read(post);

  const { title, date, description, socials } = file.data;

  unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkRehype)
    .use(rehypeStringify)
    .process(file.content)
    .then(
      (result) => {
        // I used the fields you added in your exemple
        // but if you want ALL from file.data, i suggest
        // you remove the declaration of all those variables
        // and use object destructuration in this return
        // object instead:
        // return {
        //   ...file.data,
        //   content: result.value,
        // }
        return {
          title,
          date,
          description,
          content: result.value,
          socials,
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      }
    );
}
```

```
const postDir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts');
const destDir = path.join(process.cwd(), '_data');
const jsonFile = 'post.json';

const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postDir);

generatePosts();

async function generatePosts() {
  const destPath = path.join(destDir, jsonFile)
  let posts = [];

  fileNames.forEach((fileName) => {
    const fullPath = path.join(postDir, fileName);
    posts.push(transformMdtoHtmltoJson(destPath, fullPath));
  });

  writeFile(destPath, JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2));
}

function writeFile(inFile, data) {
  fs.writeFile(inFile, data, { flag: "a+" }, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log("The file has been saved!");
    }
  );
}
```

But here again, I didn't try it, so you might need to correct a few things I didn't think of...

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot. Are you suggesting transforming all of the .md files to json first then writing to the file all at once? That does sound better.

Comment: Yeah it would make it easier on the process. I've edited my answer on how to do it, I've also took the time to optimize your code, I think there was a bit of unnecessary parts in your code. Should be a bit easier to navigate through.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I will give this a go and update you on the result.